# Unidentified Controller when using a route that calling a controller

Tags: laravel, routes, controller

Good day, and thank you for reading this problem

I have a problem where I'm using a different parameter but it doesn't work, here's the problem code

```
Route::get('/profiles','ProfilesController@index');
```

But when I'm using this code it worked perfectly fine

```
Route::get('/profiles',[ProfilesController::class, 'index']);
```

Here's the controller

```
class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return profiles::all();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use full namespace `App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController@index`

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController;

// Using PHP callable syntax...
Route::get('/profiles', [ProfilesController::class, 'index']);

// Using string syntax...
Route::get('/profiles', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController@index');
```

> If you would like to continue using the original auto-prefixed controller routing, you can simply set the value of the `$namespace` property within your `RouteServiceProvider` and update the route registrations within the `boot` method to use the `$namespace` property.

More info:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#automatic-controller-namespace-prefixing

Comment: @danielleander Don't forget to accept the correct answer.